# How make multiple aggregation on list of HashMaps with java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have an issue with java 8 implementation regarding multiple aggregation of HashMap list , (preferred with `"reduce"` function , but not must)

I need to make multiple aggregation by key name - `"service" with split("_")[0]` as in Json below:

Suppose my data structure :

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> payments = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i=0 ; ....i++){
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("service","IMAP_"+i);
      map.put("storageValue",<some value>)
      ....
      payments.add(map);
  }
```

The Json:

```
{
  "payments": [
    {
      "service": "IMAP_1",
      "storageValue": 10,
      "users": "10"
    },
    {
      "service": IMAP_2,
      "storageValue": 20,
      "users": "1"
    },
    {
      "storageValue": 200,
      "service": "Office 365 Exchange_1",
      "users": "15"
    },
    {
      "storageValue": 200,
      "service": "Office 365 Exchange_2",
      "users": "10"
    },
    {
      "storageValue": 50,
      "service": "SalesForce_1",
      "users": "100"
    }
  ]
}
```

The result should be :

```
{
      "payments": [
        {
          "service": "IMAP",
          "storageValue": 30,
          "users": "11"
        },
        {
          "storageValue": 400,
          "service": "Office 365 Exchange",
          "users": "25"
        },
        {
          "storageValue": 50,
          "service": "SalesForce",
          "users": "100"
        }
      ]
    }
```

should be something..

```
payments.stream().forEach(paymet -> {
                paymet.entrySet().stream().map(....?...).reduce()...
            );
```

Comment: Make this an object `{
          "service": "IMAP",
          "storageValue": "30",
          "users": "11"
        }`, would ease your life a lot.

Comment: @nullpointer  you are right , but it is legacy code that cannot be changed

Comment: @VitalyT Of course, it can be changed. Even when your responsibility did only cover this single operation, you were better off converting these maps to instances of a meaningful class first, perform the operation in a maintainable way using these instances and converting the resulting instances back to maps. But I doubt that this is the only part of the code you can change. At the moment you are about to create even more “legacy code that cannot be changed”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an incomplete suggestion that combines `Collectors.groupingBy` with `Collectors.reducing`.

```
Map<String,Optional<Map<String,Object>>> result = 
    payments.stream ().collect(Collectors.groupingBy (map -> map.get ("service").split ("_")[0],
                               Collectors.reducing ((m1,m2)-> {
                                   Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>();
                                   m.put("service",m1.get("service")); // you may have to remove the _1 suffix
                                   m.put("storageValue",(Integer)m1.get("storageValue")+(Integer)m2.get("storageValue"));
                                   m.put("users",(Integer)m1.get("users")+(Integer)m2.get("users"));
                                   return m;
                               })));
```

Note that since your `Map`s contain `String` values, it's a bit inconvenient to add the values of these `Map` as if they are numbers. You'll have to do some conversions from `String` to `int` and vice versa.

It might be helpful to convert each `Map` into an instance of some class having storage, users and storageValue properties. Then you can have a method that combines two such instances.

Comment: @ Eran  suppose that it's an int number...Am i need only to make sum implementation by my self ?  Can I use Java8 sum implementation instead? Thanks :)

Comment: @VitalyT suppose what is an int number? The values of your Map? In that case it would have to be a `Map<String,Object>` and you'll need to cast the value to `Integer` in order to perform addition.

Comment: You're right, changing to Object ...Can you change the answer please with sum function...

Comment: @VitalyT see edit. I didn't test it, so there may be some typos.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but i wonder if I could use with "sum" build in java8 function ?

Comment: @VitalyT what "sum" function? Integer::sum? What's wrong with using +?

Comment: how do you converting back to " List<Map<String, Object>>" .. ?

Comment: @VitalyT you can try something like `result.values().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. it isn't elegance :).

first change `service` key's value to the new value

```
 payments.stream()
            .forEach(item -> item.put("service", item.get("service").split("_")[0]));
```

then

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> mapOfMaps = payments.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(hashMap -> hashMap.get("service"),
                    hashMap -> (HashMap) hashMap,
                    YOURCLASS::merge, HashMap::new));
List<HashMap> result = new ArrayList<>(mapOfMaps.values());
```

and define a method to merge two maps like following:

```
private static HashMap<String, String> merge(HashMap<String, String> map1, HashMap<String, String> map2) {
    if (map1.get("service").equals(map2.get("service"))) {
        Long storageValue = Long.valueOf(map1.get("storageValue")) + Long.valueOf(map2.get("storageValue"));
        map1.put("storageValue", storageValue.toString());
        Long users = Long.valueOf(map1.get("users")) + Long.valueOf(map2.get("users"));
        map1.put("users", users.toString());
    }
    return map1;
}
```